# Visual studio macro __VA_ARGS__ not unpacked correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros

I work on a project, and I need to simulate a recursive macro (here TEST_COLUMN). But it fail on visual 2013.
On gcc, it work correctly, but with visual, I have an error.
So, to debug this macro, I use static_assert (maybe there is a better way).
Each time, in the macros TEST_COLUMN_X(name, ...) the value of name contain ALL the parameters, and not only the first one.

If anyone have an idea to fix this.
Here is the minimal code needed to reproduce it:

```
#define STR_HELPER(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_HELPER(x) //transform x to char

#define EXPAND(x) x
#define NUM_ARGS_HELPER(X,X64,X63,X62,X61,X60,X59,X58,X57,X56,X55,X54,X53,X52,X51,X50,X49,X48,X47,X46,X45,X44,X43,X42,X41,X40,X39,X38,X37,X36,X35,X34,X33,X32,X31,X30,X29,X28,X27,X26,X25,X24,X23,X22,X21,X20,X19,X18,X17,X16,X15,X14,X13,X12,X11,X10,X9,X8,X7,X6,X5,X4,X3,X2,X1,N,...) N
//count to number of argument containing 
#define NUM_ARGS(...) EXPAND(NUM_ARGS_HELPER(0, __VA_ARGS__ ,64,63,62,61,60,59,58,57,56,55,54,53,52,51,50,49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40,39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)) in __VA_ARGS__

//define each level of the macro
#define TEST_COLUMN_0            ;
#define TEST_COLUMN_1(name)      static_assert(false,"TEST_COLUMN_1 " STR(name));
#define TEST_COLUMN_2(name,...)  static_assert(false,"TEST_COLUMN_2 " STR(name)); //TEST_COLUMN_1(__VA_ARGS__)
#define TEST_COLUMN_3(name,...)  static_assert(false,"TEST_COLUMN_3 " STR(name)); //TEST_COLUMN_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define TEST_COLUMN_4(name,...)  static_assert(false,"TEST_COLUMN_4 " STR(name)); TEST_COLUMN_3(__VA_ARGS__)

//tricks to call the correct macro (TEST_COLUMN_X)
#define TEST_COLUMN_N1(N,...) TEST_COLUMN_##N(__VA_ARGS__)
#define TEST_COLUMN(N,...) TEST_COLUMN_N1(N,__VA_ARGS__)

//recursive macro
#define TEST_STATIC_COLUMN(...) TEST_COLUMN(NUM_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    TEST_STATIC_COLUMN(a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
main.cpp(21): error C2338: TEST_COLUMN_3 a, b, c
```

but it should be

```
    main.cpp(21): error C2338: TEST_COLUMN_3 a
```

You can test this using the online compiler http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/

Comment: The preprocessor is dialect-ful, to put it that way. All implementations differ in subtle ways. I think if I were to do anything non-trivial with macros, except the common "apply", I would use the Boost preprocessor library, which abstracts away the differences.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but adding some call to EXPAND solve this issue:

```
#define TEST_COLUMN_2(name,...)  static_assert(false,"TEST_COLUMN_2 " STR(name)); EXPAND(TEST_COLUMN_1(__VA_ARGS__))
#define TEST_COLUMN_3(name,...)  static_assert(false,"TEST_COLUMN_3 " STR(name)); EXPAND(TEST_COLUMN_2(__VA_ARGS__))
#define TEST_COLUMN_4(name,...)  static_assert(false,"TEST_COLUMN_4 " STR(name)); EXPAND(TEST_COLUMN_3(__VA_ARGS__))
#define TEST_COLUMN_N1(N,...) EXPAND(TEST_COLUMN_##N(__VA_ARGS__))
```